# How do I write/update data to multiple child nodes via Firebase Cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've got a database that looks like this:

[image]

I want to reset the `Patient_List` and `Current_Token` children to 0 at a particular time (say 12 AM) automatically for all the users in the database.

I went through the Firebase cloud function docs and these projects on gitHub:
[Deleting nodes](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-old-child-nodes/functions/index.js/) and [Delete unused user accounts using Cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/delete-unused-accounts-cron).
Both of the above examples update and change data based on a particular UID i.e update only particular nodes based on the UID passed.
I would like to know if it is possible to update values for the above child elements in all the nodes and if so , how would it be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a single update statement affect a child of all database nodes under some location.  You will have to iterate all the nodes (by querying/reading them somehow), then update each one that you find.  This is potentially a costly operation in terns of bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Only use the general ref, and before that reference all nodes that you want to update, just like this:

```
var gralRef = firebase.database().ref();
var obj_update={};                              
obj_update[`users/${firstuser}/name`]='John';
obj_update[`users/${seconduser}/name`]='Mark';
obj_update[`users/${seconduser}/address`]='New York';   


gralRef.update(obj_update);
```