# How to write a new key to every existing UID with Firebase Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to write a new key to every existing UID when a new notification sent.

The code works like this; When a new message is written to realtime database a new notification is sent to every device.

So far it works in my code.

But I want to write to the existing UID's, a new entry for notification count badge in my android app to show unread count.

EDIT: Problem is solved. See next code block.

Here is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

/** NOTIFICATIONS */


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        const notification = snapshot.val();
        const title = notification.title;


        const topic = 'notifications';

        const message = {
            data: {
                title: notification.title,
                body: notification.message,
                link: notification.link,
            },
            topic: topic
        };


        // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        admin.messaging().send(message)
            .then((response: String) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message: ', response);
                writeBadge()

            })
            .catch((error: String) => {
                console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
            });



        return null;
    });

    // The problem is in this function

function writeBadge() {


    return admin.database().ref('/users').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot => {
            const uid = userSnapshot.key;

            const myRef = admin.database().ref("/users/" + uid + "/badge").push();
            const key = myRef.key;
            userSnapshot.child("badge/" + key).set({
                key: true
            });

            console.log('Pushed UID: ' + uid);


        }));

    });
}
```

This is the answer I was looking. This works for me.

```
function writeBadge() {


    return admin.database().ref('/users').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot => {
            const uid = userSnapshot.key;

            const myRef = admin.database().ref("/users/" + uid + "/badge").push();

            myRef.set({
                key: true
            });

            console.log('Pushed UID: ' + uid);


        }));

    });
}
```

Comment: "I want to write to the existing UID's, a new entry for notification count badge in my android app to show unread count."
Did you already try anything? What's the problem you have when implementing this part of your use case?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024212/how-do-i-write-update-data-to-multiple-child-nodes-via-firebase-cloud-functions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429370/firebase-cloud-function-update-all-entries-in-database/52444994#52444994